# iOS9 UILabels need adjusting again

Tags: uilabel, ios9

I don't know if it is something that I am doing wrong but each time there is a significant iOS update 6 to 7, 7 to 8 and again from 8 to 9 some `UILabel` seem to not be big enough and I see " ..." as the label is truncated. I now have to go through the app and reset all the sizes of such fields. Does anyone else have this this problem and if so is there a way of fixing it for good?

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout? Also, do you mean `UITextField` or `UILabel`? `UITextField` is used for editable text and shouldn't truncate with an ellipsis unless specifically asked to. Also, with no code it's pretty much impossible to comment on what you're doing because we have no idea what you are actually doing.

Comment: Oh yes - labels. Will edit question. I use the storyboard to set the layout and labels and the size of these does not change programmatically so I am not sure the code will help. It is just really annoying that every time there is an iOS update it does this to most of them.

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout? Which font are you using?

Comment: Let me know if you're using AutoLayout and which font you are selecting for the labels in Interface Builder. There is plenty that can change the size of a label without the text changing.

Comment: The font is the system font. I am not sure about the autolayout. This is not turned on as far as I am aware .... all autolayout settings are greyed out in Xcode so I guess not.

Comment: I am using a label with a width constraint and got the same problem. It does not seems to be so easy like just use auto layout.

Comment: @Joqus - sadly not. I went through and changed all the labels manually.

Comment: @RichardGriffiths I also have some problems with animations in iOS 9. Very annoying. Instead of coding my app functionality I have to deal with this breaks in new versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah. The thing here is a double cause between the system font and not using AutoLayout.

First, use AutoLayout. It has been around for over 3 years now and is required to support some of the iOS 9 features.

Second, using AutoLayout will fix your label problem. There isn't a second step.

Between iOS 6 and 7 the system font changed from Helvetica to Helvetica Neue. Between 8 and 9 it changed from Helvetica Neue to San Francisco.

These font changes will mean the text has a different intrinsic size. If this size is slightly larger then it will cause your labels to truncate.

So, why auto layout? This intrinsic content size is used everywhere in AutoLayout. You define the position of your labels in constraints and then let the auto layout system size the label according to the content.

Actually, third point. If a uses uses large font sizes in the accessibility options this will also increase the size of the font and cause them to truncate. Auto Layout fixes this also.

If you want help with any auto layout stuff there are some great tutorials on the Ray Wenderlich site and his book is good too.

Comment: A great answer and the change of font is a good explanation as to what is happening. Frustrating!! I will look to into auto layout. Many thanks.

Comment: @RichardGriffiths glad I could help. If you need any help with AutoLayout check StackOverflow or give me a shout (just leave a comment here) and I'll try to help.